# What mathematics cannot be reduced to pigeonhole?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, big-list, pigeonhole-principle, big-picture

Pigeonhole is a fundamental principle without which state of mathematics will be much different. However what examples of good mathematics has not yet been proved and cannot be proved with pigeonhole alone?

Comment: Pythagoras' theorem

Comment: Please post with explanation. Is Euler characteristic of planar graph provable?

Comment: @edm explicit and implicit are same if principle exists in proof.

Comment: Establishing that a given result/technique isn't sufficient to prove a given theorem is generally extremely hard to do, mostly because *precisely defining* what that means is extremely subtle. For example, the reverse-mathematical approach Bjorn mentions below takes as "trivial" a large amount of non-trivial mathematics (e.g. the fundamental theorem of algebra). But there are many basic results for which the pigeonhole principle seems completely irrelevant; e.g. how would you use it to prove the Pythagorean theorem (per Hagen's comment above)?

Comment: So your starting instinct here should definitely be that the pigeonhole principle - or anything else specific, really - will *not* be sufficient to tackle most problems you'll come across.

Comment: Lots of things.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Is Euler Characteristic of planar graph provable with Pigeonhole?

Answer (score 7):

The [infinite pigeonhole principle](http://www.sendailogic.com/SLS2014/shafer-slides.pdf)
 is equivalent to B$\Sigma^0_2$ in the sense of reverse mathematics.

This implies that many theorems such as Heine-Borel, Konig's lemma, Ramsey's theorem are not provable from this Infinite Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: Possible to be more explicit in applications?

Comment: @Brout That's a pretty explicit list of applications. Are you familiar with the theorems listed?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Except for Ramsey's theorem No.